# How to show validation errors for a login form when fields are empty on submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I'm using the Devise gem for authentication and for the login form when I click on "Log in" with the fields blank I get the error "Invalid Email or password". I think it would be nice just like the registration form to have errors like "Name can't be blank" or "Email can't be blank" depending on the field that is blank. How can one achieve that?

`Log in view`

```
<h2>Log in</h2>
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), data: { turbo: false }) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "current-password" %>
    </div>
    <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
      <div class="field remember">
        <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
        <%= f.label :remember_me %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

`application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :update_allowed_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def after_sign_up_path_for(_resource)
    groups_path
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(_resource)
    groups_path
  end

  protected

  def update_allowed_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) do |u|
      u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: One thing you need to keep in mind here is that for security reasons you should provide the same response no matter if its the password or email thats invalid. You do not want to let an attacker performing a brute force attack know that they have found a valid email as that makes the it so much easier. I would just add a client side validation if you feel that its needed.

Comment: @max If I understood you correctly, I'm not trying to change the response "Invalid email or password" if either or both of the credentials fail. Currently, when a user doesn't provide an email and password and then clicks "Log in" submitting empty fields, it still says "Invalid Email or Password" yet nothing was sent to the server. I feel like it's better in such a scenario to respond with "Name can't be blank" and "Email can't be blank". What do you think?

Comment: YAGNI. I think that the Devise solution provides enough user feedback and avoids the potential pitfalls. If you really want to provide more feedback its trivial to just add a client side validation like for example customizing the view and adding the `required` attribute to the inputs.

Comment: If you REALLY want to do this on the server side you would use the [Form object pattern](https://dev.to/drbragg/rails-design-patterns-form-object-4d47) or manually add errors to the record in the controller. The sessions controller does not trigger validations in the model by design since models aren't context aware besides their normal lifecycle. Since its a new record all the validations for creating a record would be triggered. But I can think of a lot of better things to spend your time on.

Answer (score -1):

Its pretty trivial to just add a client side validation which will provide immediate feedback if you want to:

```
# app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb
<h2>Log in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "current-password", required: true %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>`
```

The views in your application will take priority over those defined by the engine.

The reason why Devise doesn't actually use model validation at all for sessions is that models are not context aware and adding this feature would add a lot of complexity for very little gain.

Your model doesn't have a concept of "signing in" so if you called `resource.valid?` it will fire all the validations for creating a record like for example uniqueness of the email.

While you could do this by creating a form object or by overriding the controller method and adding the errors "inline" it provides very little additional value in safeguarding your application against bad user input which is what server side validations are primarily intendended to do (user feedback is the secondary purpose). **YAGNI**.

Comment: Thank you for all the explanations. I totally agree with you, it's trivial.

Comment: I'm not sure if the generated form is missing the required attributes just because Devise is quite old.

Comment: I'm new to learning `Rails` and I installed and set up `Devise` as per the documentation and the attributes weren't generated. But no problem I'll just add them manually.